# How to call a method from WebSocketHandler to RequestHandler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

Here my sample code.

```
    class PDF(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
            self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.txt"')
            self.write('sdsadjs')

class RealtimeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    pdf = PDF() ## Here I intialized the obeject
```

When I intialized the object it throws the below error.

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

`RequestHandler` has [following definition](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler):

```
class tornado.web.RequestHandler(application, request, **kwargs)
```

You need to pass at least two arguments (`application` and `request`) to initialize it or the inherited class. But I really don't understand why are you trying to do so. This class is used to be initialized by internal logic of `Tornado` during each request.

I'm sure you're doing wrong thing. You should probably check out [the documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler) and decide what you really need.

P.S. It would be nice if you provide some except of what you're trying to archive.